# Cannot find Inf2Cat in Windows 10

Tags: window

I need to find `Inf2Cat` in Windows 10.

I already downloaded and installed Windows development Kits.
There is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin`, but there is no `Inf2Cat`.
Can anyone advise how to find this app?

Comment: Can you please add how you tried to find it at microsoft?